# "gatsby-plugin-sharp" plugin Couldn't be found when gatsby develop command is ran

Tags: reactjs, npm, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

Got a new pc and cloned my project from GitHub, then run `npm install` but then it installed with lots of errors, so now I ran `gatsby develop` and got the error messages below. please assist me

**ERROR #10226  CONFIG**

Couldn't find the "gatsby-plugin-sharp" plugin declared in "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\IamJude\gatsby-config.js".

Tried looking for a local plugin in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\IamJude\plugins\gatsby-plugin-sharp.

Tried looking for an installed package in the following paths:

- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\IamJude\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\load-themes\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\IamJude\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\IamJude\node_modules\gatsby\dist\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\IamJude\node_modules\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\IamJude\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- C:\Users\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- C:\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp

not finished open and validate gatsby-configs - 1.329s

ERROR

The above error occurred in the  component:
in CLI (created by ConnectedCLI)
in ConnectedCLI
in StoreStateProvider
in App

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, App.

ERROR

Warning: App: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI.

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\yoga-layout-prebuilt\yoga-layout\build\Release\nbind.js:53
throw ex;
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'activities' of undefined
at getGlobalStatus (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\reporter\redux\utils.js:25:54)
at createPendingActivity (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\reporter\redux\internal-actions.js:114:51)
at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\redux\lib\redux.js:483:35
at prematureEnd (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\reporter\catch-exit-signals.js:39:38)
at Reporter.panic (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\reporter\reporter.js:72:42)
at process. (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\index.js:79:21)
at process.emit (events.js:327:22)
at processEmit (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:161:32)
at process.emit (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules@turist\fetch\dist\sourcemap-register.js:926:21)
at processEmit [as emit] (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\IamJude\node_modules\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:161:32)
at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)

Answer (score 2):

What is the contents of your package.json?

Do you having `gatsby-plugin-sharp` installed?

Maybe try `npm install --save gatsby-plugin-sharp`

Comment: didn't work after i installed gatsby-plugin-sharp, throw a lot of errors

Comment: It didnt work me either initially...I also had to do: npm install react  --save and  npm uninstall react-dom  and npm install react-dom --save and it worked

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you may need to make add a few extra packages to make the project run. First of all, I will try to add manually the `gatsby-plugin-sharp` by:

```
npm install --save gatsby-plugin-sharp
```

If the error persists, you may need to add `windows-build-tools` as you can see in the [Gatsby on Windows documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-on-windows/):

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015
```

The command above, upon installing this package, it downloads and installs Visual C++ Build Tools 2015, provided free of charge by Microsoft. These tools are required to compile popular native modules. It will also install Python 2.7, configuring your machine and npm appropriately.

If your `windows-build-tools` installation stalls after Visual Studio Build Tools finishes, [this remedy might help](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/47#issuecomment-296881488).

Comment: the windows-build-tools installed successfully but the gatsby plugin sharp didn't. Throw up errors 


PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\IamJude> npm install --save gatsby-plugin-sharp

> sharp@0.25.4 install C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\IamJude\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp\node_modules\sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install --runtime=napi) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Using cached C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_libvips\libvips-8.9.1-win32-x64.tar.gz